# mysql and 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cron

i'm working on a site that handles free subscriptions and i will like to now how to cancel their subscriptions after 30 days inactivity, i know that this has to be done with cron-jobs  but i have no idea on how to count 30 after the last time the user logged in?

Comment: How do you know when a user last logged in? I mean, let's say you had to do it manually, how would you go about it?

Comment: @Raj It took me a second or two to realize the intent behind your question. I almost answered it. :P

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) > last_logged_in_date
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use mysql DATE_ADD function

`SELECT DATE_ADD('YOUR DATE', INTERVAL 30 day)`

See mysql manual for more info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add.

You can do it in 1 UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE yourTable SET active = 0 WHERE validity_date < CURRENT_DATE
```

And when they subscribe, you receive payment

```
UPDATE yourTable SET active = 1, validity_date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE id = 'somekind of id'
```

Answer (score 1):

And if one does not want to use cron and using a MySQL 5.1 or greater one can use event.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query that will get you that. In fact, the MySQL documentation has your example exactly. Do a quick search for "30 days" on this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html.