# Calculate 30 days Ago PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, triggers, cron

I am pulling the lastBillingDate from my DB. It is a normal timestamp. I want to have the system check to see if the timestamp is 30 days ago. Basically we bill a customer every 30 days. What I'd like is it to trigger the function when the date is exactly 30 days, or over 30 days. This doesn't seem to be working. Here is an example of one of my timestamps too:

```
1339477200
```

Here's the cron function:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
                $result = mysql_query($query);      

                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

                        $id = $row[0];
                        $ownerID = $row[1];
                        $company = $row[4];
                        $lastBillDate = $row[36];

                        echo $lastBillDate.'<br>';

                    if($lastBillDate<strtotime('-30 days')){
                        $billdate = RelativeTime($lastBillDate);

                                    mailBillNotice($id, $ownerID, $company, $billdate);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: To expand on what @alexn said, you should probably use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and get the column using it's named key. For example: `$row['billDate']` if your MySQL column is called `billDate`. You shouldn't really be using the `mysql_*` functions; they're deprecated. Have a look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtracting a certain number of hours, days, months or years from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382458/subtracting-a-certain-number-of-hours-days-months-or-years-from-date), but you should really let SQL handle this IMHO.

Comment: Another possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621350/mysql-and-30-days?rq=1

Comment: None of these answers work...

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, it would be better to put that criteria in the SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE last_bill_date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

That will return only the contacts that have a `last_bill_date` that is 30 or more days back from today. Then do whatever processing you need, bill the clients, and update the timestamp.

Comment: I tried that, it shows none. I know the timestamp shown above is past 30 days. Shows nothing.

Comment: Is the timestamp in the above post (1339477200) a real timestamp from the database?

Comment: In that particular case, the timestamp converts to June 12th, which at the time of writing (July 6) is not 30 days ago, so that record won't show up.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as it's just a number, you can use normal arithmetic on your timestamp:

```
$timestamp = 1339477200;
$thirtyDays = (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
$thirtyDaysAgo = time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)

if($timestamp - $thirtyDays <= $thirtyDaysAgo) {
    // Do your thang
}
```

Doing it in MySQL, however, is much more sensible. It removes the overhead of fetching extra rows from the database. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts 
WHERE 
    last_bill_date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: It might not matter in this particular case (though billing is an area I would be cautious), but it is generally a mistake to assume that a day contains 24 hours, an hour 60 minutes, or a minute 60 seconds. Don't do this!

Comment: @Conrad Thank you, that's a good point although I do agree that in this case it's not critical.

Comment: @JamWaffles This doesn't seem to work.. I tried the SQL statement